# Load JavaScript Object from Server

Tags: javascript, php

i want to download a JavaScrip Object from server.

If i declare the object for test it works:

```
    var src = {
  "a":1,
  "b":2,
  "c":3
}
```

but if I try this:

```
 $.get('http://serveraddress/getParts.php', function(data) {  /* at this point data consist of ["a":"0","b":"1","c:"2"] */   src = data; });
```

It fails, src is undefined.
What's wrong with it?

Thank's for help

Comment: where are you declaring and using that src variable

Comment: You just requested a URL from the server there, nothing more - the browser does not know that you want this interpreted as JavaScript now. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/ exists.